# Binding a RadCombobox inside a radgrid

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik, radgrid

Please can someone point me in the right direction, i have a radcombobox inside the radgrid, as soon as i edit the row it loses it's value

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="SupplierRegion" UniqueName="SupplierRegion" HeaderText="Region">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="SupplierRegionHyperlink" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierRegion")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="SupplierRegionRadComboBox" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
                            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetRegions" Path="~/WebServices/SuppliersWS.asmx"></WebServiceSettings>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

and the below is my C# code

```
      if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
                GridEditCommandColumn editColumn = (GridEditCommandColumn)SupplierSearchGrid.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn");
                if (!editColumn.Visible)
                    editColumn.Visible = true;
                GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;

                RadComboBox SupplierRegionValue = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("SupplierRegionRadComboBox");

                SupplierRegionValue.SelectedValue = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["RegionID"].ToString();
                SupplierRegionValue.Text = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["Description"].ToString();

            }
```

in my edit it can't seem to find the Combobox as it returns null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind data to radcombobox inside grid EditItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056323/how-to-bind-data-to-radcombobox-inside-grid-edititemtemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at topic [How to bind data to radcombobox inside grid EditItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056323/how-to-bind-data-to-radcombobox-inside-grid-edititemtemplate)

XAML

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="SupplierRegion" UniqueName="SupplierRegion" HeaderText="Region">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="SupplierRegionHyperlink" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierRegion")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="SupplierRegionRadComboBox" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="true" >
                            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetRegions" Path="~/WebServices/SuppliersWS.asmx"></WebServiceSettings>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"
                HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

C#

```
protected void gvSupplierRegion_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem myGridItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

        if (myGridItem.IsInEditMode)
        {
            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)myGridItem["SupplierRegion"].FindControl("SupplierRegionRadComboBox");
            combo.DataSource = GetUploadStatus();
            combo.DataTextField = "Value";
            combo.DataValueField = "Key";
            combo.DataBind();
            combo.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(myGridItem.DataItem, "UploadStatus").ToString();
        }
```

}

Comment: But my datasource is the webservice which I call load on demand, should i set it here as well

Answer (score 0):

so for these with the same issue i found the solution

in the aspx page add the the webservice's id and description colum id in the datakeynames, then in your radcombobox in the edititemtemplate

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="SupplierRegion" UniqueName="SupplierRegion" HeaderText="Region">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description")%>'
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="SupplierRegionRadComboBox" AllowCustomText="false" EnableLoadOnDemand="true"  AutoPostBack="true"  Text='<%#Bind("Description") %>'  >
                            <WebServiceSettings Method="GetRegions" Path="~/WebServices/SuppliersWS.asmx"></WebServiceSettings>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

and in the code behind

```
  protected void SuppliersSearchRadGrid2_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editItem.FindControl("SupplierRegionRadComboBox");
            combo.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(editItem.DataItem, "RegionID").ToString();
            
        }
      
    }
```